# How can you move text to the end of a line in a docx file using python-docx?

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I have text like

```
"word1 word2"
```

and want to change it to

`"word1_______________word2"` (underscores are spaces)

Adding just enough spaces to keep `word1` and `word2` on the same line in a docx file.

I'm afraid I don't really have a good idea of a solution for this.  Each character in MS Word takes up a different amount of space. So unfortunately I cannot simply use `len(string)` and add enough spaces to approach an integer value for the line.

My `word1` and `word2` instances are all variable lengths, but the space on each line in the docx file is fixed.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: One way is to create a table, where each cell is left/right justified.  Adding spaces is (potentially) asking for a world of issues down the road.

Comment: Yeah, using spaces for alignment is bad Juju. Have you considered using tabstops?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace a sequence of words in a Word Document with another sequence then you can iterate over the text in each sequence of Run instances in each paragraph, and replace the source sequence with the target sequence. This assumes the two words have the same formatting so will be of part of the same Run instance; i.e. if one word is **BOLD** and the other is not then that sequence of text will be split into two different Run instances.

```python
from docx import Document

source = 'word1 word2'
# if wanted to add 12 spaces between the 2 words
target = source.replace(' ', ' ' * 12)
print(f"Replace source: '{source}' with '{target}'")

doc = Document(f)

for p in doc.paragraphs:
    for r in p.runs:
        r.text = r.text.replace(source, target)

doc.save('newdoc.docx')
```

Adding "just enough spaces" to keep `word1` and `word2` on the same line is tricky without seeing a sample. If there is text preceding "word1 word2" sequence then the alignment is based on position of `word1` with respect its position in the paragraph in addition to the font type and size for that Run instance. You could add a new line before any "word1 word2" sequence so it always starts on a new line.